# Install apps permanently on Android?

Tags: android

On Android can users choose to install any apps permanently?

And if so how does this work? I know when you first get an Android there are pre-installed apps that are permanent and you cant uninstall them but is there anyway in which we can permanently install apps ourselves?

Comment: Write a custom ROM and include them in /system partition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By permanantly, I assume installing them as System Apps.

For that, you might need to root your phone. Google "installing android app as system app" and you will get a lot of answers. [This is one sample](http://www.androidauthority.com/install-user-app-as-system-app-how-to-93522/)

As the question is generic, so I am not adding the steps.

Easy way- If you don't uninstall an app, it will stay there permanantly. In addition, you can use additional security for preventing accidental uninstallation.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is a 'system app'.

> The apps installed on your *Android* devices can be broadly categorized as *system apps* or *user apps*, based on their installation location. The user apps are just all your normal app installations through the Google Play Store, Amazon Appstore or sideloading. These go into the `/data` partition of your Android phone, which is the part of the internal memory made available for user data and apps.
>
> System apps are basically the apps that come pre-installed with your *ROM*. In a standard Android user environment, the user doesn’t have write access to the `/system` partition and thus, installing or uninstalling system apps directly isn’t possible. The process isn’t as hard as it may sound. However, there is a catch.
>
> In order to install an app as a system app on your Android device, your device must either be _root_ed, or have a *custom recovery* installed (or both).

Here's [how to install an app as a system app](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/)